# Sudden application termination

Tags: objective-c, instruments, xcode-instruments

My application is terminating without error. I debugged the code and everything is in place.
I found in instruments that sudden termination is due to "unauthorized file system access" and detail pane has unauthorized access for:

```
Caller:imageloader::link(imageloader::linkcontext const&, bool, bool ,imageloader::rpathchain const&) and Mode:O_RDWR and Function:Open
```

also for,

```
Caller:checkAddress Mode:blank  Function:write
```

How to remove this unauthorized file system access.

Comment: Is this happening on the device and in the simulator, or just one or the other?

Comment: Is your application sandboxed? You don't mention whether this is an OS X or iOS application.

Comment: @MikeS: Yes, it is happening on both device and simulator.

Comment: @craig: it is iOS application. Im not sure if it is sandboxed. How do we check that!!

Comment: If it's an iOS application, it's automatically sandboxed. What file are you attempting to access? Are you saving data somewhere, when your application terminates?